# Using Tkinter I am trying to add a user-entered value and add it to a value that exists in a file, but it isn't working

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a very simple loyalty program for my small business. This is my first project in Python or Tkinter.

The #POINT ENTRY section below lets the user enter in the appropriate amount of points. It then uses "addpoints" to pull the current points from a text file (with the extension ".cust") and add what the user entered and write it back to the text file.

Unfortunately what it's actually doing is just replacing that whole line with ".!Entry26"

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#POINT ENTRY
pointlabel = Label(root, text="Enter Earned/Spent Points")
pointlabel.pack()
pointlabel.place(x = 46, y = 95)
pointenter = Entry(root, bg="#E9E9E9")
pointenter.config(font="bold")
pointenter.pack()
pointenter.place(x = 50, y = 120, height="30", width="140")
addbutton = Button(root, bg="green", fg="white", text="   +   ", command=addpoints)
addbutton.config(font='bold')
addbutton.pack()
addbutton.place(x = 201, y = 118)
subbutton = Button(root, bg="red", text="-")
subbutton.config(font='bold')
subbutton.pack()
subbutton.place(x = 251, y = 118)


def addpoints():
    file = open("assets\\" + IDentry.get() + ".cust", 'r+')
    currpts = file.read(0)
    updatepoints = sum(currpts, pointenter)
    file.write(str(updatepoints))
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a woking example:

Try:

```
from tkinter import *
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.pointenter = Entry(root,font=(None, 14), width=50)
        self.pointenter.pack()
        addbutton = Button(root, bg="green", fg="white", text="   +   ", command=self.addpoints)
        addbutton.config(font='bold')
        addbutton.pack()

    def addpoints(self):
        self.currpts = '50' # a string
        print(float(self.currpts)+ float(self.pointenter.get()))

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

One thing I found very useful when I first started was to do a print() on all variables. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I replaced the "updatepoints" line with your suggestion and it gives me an error:
"line 98, in addpoints
    sum(float(currpts), float(pointenter))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the .cust extension with a .txt extension. In addition, here are some errors that you have.

The `addpoints()` function should be moved above the tkinter code. It is being called in the tkinter section of code, and it needs to be defined before it is called.

```
updatepoints = sum(currpts, pointenter)
```

Should become:

```
updatepoints = int(currpts) + int(pointenter.get())
```

`currpts` is a string, and it needs to be converted into an integer. `pointenter` is a tkinter object and you need to get a string from it using `.get()`. Then convert it into an integer.

Also, I would open and close the file twice, once to read and once again to write. Otherwise the new number would just be appended to the existing text in the file instead of replacing it.

Here is an example:

```
file = open("examplefile.txt", "r")
currpts = file.read(1)
file.close()
print(currpts)
updatepoints = int(currpts) + int(pointenter.get())
print(updatepoints)
writefile = open("test3.txt", "w")
writefile.write(str(updatepoints))
writefile.close()
```

Comment: The file suffix doesn't matter at all.